# Are there any advantages of using "When" clause in oracle trigger?

Tags: triggers, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g and would like to know if there are any specific advantages using "When" clause. Below are a couple of ways (both work) that my trigger can be written. I want to know if there is any difference in terms of performance.

```
Create or Replace Trigger Validate_EMP_T1 on EMP

    After Insert     OR Update 
    On EMP For Each Row
    BEGIN
        IF  UPDATING THEN
            IF  :NEW.salary         !=  :OLD.salary
            OR  :NEW.dept_no        !=  :OLD.dept_no THEN
                .
            END IF;
        ELSIF    INSERTING THEN
            IF  :NEW.salary     !=  0 THEN
                .
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END;

    OR

    Create or Replace Trigger Validate_EMP_T1 on EMP
    After Insert     OR Update 
    On EMP For Each Row
    WHEN ( UPDATING  AND (  NEW.salary  != OLD.salary 
                         OR NEW.dept_no != OLD.dept_no )
        OR INSERTING AND    NEW.salary  != 0             )
    BEGIN
        IF  UPDATING THEN
            .
        ELSIF    INSERTING THEN
            .
        END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a difference, the trigger with the `WHEN` clause should be slightly more efficient since it doesn't require the trigger to be invoked if the `WHEN` clause isn't satisfied.  Whether that difference is large enough to be meaningful to you is something that you would have to benchmark.  If you're building an application that is trying to support millions of transactions per second and the vast majority of those transactions don't satisfy the `WHEN` clause, the difference may be meaningful (though in that case you'd almost certainly want to avoid using triggers in the first place).  If you're building a line of business application that a few dozen people use, the difference probably isn't measurable.

Comment: Thanks Justin. That helps. The trigger is written on a table that has about a thousand transactions per second.

Comment: @pradeepbn - I wouldn't suggest creating a trigger on a table that is going to have a thousand transactions per second.  That would be way too inefficient.  I'd be much more interested in designing a more appropriate and efficient architectural solution rather than optimizing the performance of the trigger.